# Issues with adding figtext to bottom of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a series of footnotes using `plt.figtext` to a set of subplots, and cannot get them all to show up when I print out to file using either the `plt.savefig()` command, or `%matplotlib notebook` save to file option.

The list of footnotes is pretty long and looks like (when rendered to screen, which works fine):[image: Desired output of figures and footnotes]

However, when I print to file they get cut off:[image: Undesired output]

I set my figure size for the subplot to `plt.figure(figsize=(7,10))`
and used `plt.tight_layout()` to format the subplots so that the axes didn't mash up with the titles.

I have been trying for the life of me to find a way to extend the size of the output to account for the footnotes AND the subplots, but have had absolutely no luck. This does not seem like an unreasonable use case, by any stretch of the imagination.

***EDIT***

The text is generated after each subplot is created, along the lines of:

```
plt.legend(loc=6, fontsize=10)
#plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.xlim(0, 45)
plt.ylim(2.5, 5.5)
plt.xlabel('Distance (km)', alpha=.75)
plt.ylabel('Pace (min/km)', alpha=.75)
plt.title('Top 4 Male Finishers and SA 2016 Twin Cities Marathon Timed$^1$ Splits$^2$')
plt.figtext(0.814, 0.01, '1 Provided by mtecResults', horizontalalignment='right', fontsize=6) 
plt.figtext(0.88, 0.0, '2 Mean time per unit distance between two points', horizontalalignment='right', fontsize=6) 
plt.figtext(0.845, -0.01, '3 SA Finished 670 out of 4716 Males', horizontalalignment='right', fontsize=6)
plt.figtext(0.845, -0.02, '4 SA Finished 754 out of 4756 Males', horizontalalignment='right', fontsize=6)
```

Comment: See below. It didn't work for me for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are of course a multitude of options how to make sure some text label is acutally within the figure when saving.

#### 1. the `bbox_inches` argument

You may choose not to use `plt.tight_layout()`, because this ignores text added as a text label. You can then use the `bbox_inches` argument to `plt.savefig`:

```
plt.savefig("output.png", bbox_inches = "tight")
```

This method increases the figure size until all text is included.

Placing the text would best be done using `verticalalignment ="top"` and placing the test close to y=0 in figure coordinates. Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.gca()

text = """1 Provided by mtecResults
2 Mean time per unit distance between two points
3 SA Finished 670 out of 4716 Males
4 SA Finished 754 out of 4756 Males"""

plt.figtext(0.05,0.00, text, fontsize=8, va="top", ha="left")

plt.savefig(__file__+".png", bbox_inches = "tight")
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### 2. Add margin to figure.

You may use `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4)` to make more space around the axes, which can then be filled with the text. For the other dimensions use arguments `top`, `left`, `right`, depending on where the text sits.
This option requires the text to be positionned within the figure. It will not change the figure size, but reduce the size of the axes.

Placing the text would best be done using `verticalalignment ="bottom"` and placing the test close to but above y=0 in figure coordinates. Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.gca()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

text = """1 Provided by mtecResults
2 Mean time per unit distance between two points
3 SA Finished 670 out of 4716 Males
4 SA Finished 754 out of 4756 Males"""

plt.figtext(0.05,0.01, text, fontsize=8, va="bottom", ha="left")

plt.savefig(__file__+"2.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention in my OP that I did try `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=x)`, but without `plt.tight_layout()` (with x being various values) with no success. However, with  `plt.tight_layout()` it seems to do the magic. Thanks!

Comment: How exactly `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4)` would help, depends on how you place the text. Since you kept it secret how you place the text, I cannot help you with that.

Comment: See edit above. I could post that in a separate thread, but it was basically hit-and-miss, along the lines of `plt.figtext(0.814, 0.01, '1 Provided by mtecResults', horizontalalignment='right', fontsize=6)`, etc. I was wondering if there was some magical way of aligning the text to some particular position, specifically, because getting the  x-coordinate lined up for each `figtext` object in kind of a royal PITA.

Comment: By lined up you mean you want to have the text centered? Why not use `ha="center"` instead of `ha="right"`?

Comment: Actually, just tried, `ha="left"` with the `x` coord set to 0. Simple... Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer to include examples for both methods and the respective coordinate settings.